# SSIS Task for error row redirect

Tags: ssis

Exporting some data from sql server to excel.  Any rows that are truncated or error out, I want to catch the row so it can be handled manually. I have set the Data Conversion error handling to Redirect Row, but not sure what destination task to use for the catch.

Edit - I tried a flat file destination, but it wants all the rows converted to text. This seems like it is going to create a kind of error catching tree with conversions and flat files.

Comment: Flat File Destination

Comment: I am setting it up and I get an error, one of my columns is using the DT_NTEXT type and the txt file wont accept it.  Am I going to have to do a conversion first?

Comment: See if this helps:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143924/converting-dt-ntext-to-dt-text